# is there an R package to run multiple imputation with an lme() model?

Tags: r, imputation

per the title, I have an analysis with which I am trying to run a multiple imputation and a lme() model with a single random term. mice() does not seem to allow for this and I have not been able to find another package that states it can handle lme(). Does anyone know of a package that does?

Comment: The [CRAN Task View on Missing Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MissingData.html) is a good place to look for this. It has a few recommendations for missing data in mixed effects models.

Answer (score 1):

found it: it's the "micemd" package or just use the "mice" package + import library(broom.mixed)

Comment: I would be curious to know what doesn't work about the `mice`/`lme` combination.  I thought `mice` was a more-or-less general purpose imputation engine?

Comment: So your thought is correct. I also just found that mice can handle lme, if you make sure to have library(broom.mixed) in your environment. Without broom.mixed it throws errors when trying to run with() to apply the linear mixed model to the imputed data sets.

Comment: You could add that to your answer.  I'm sure `micemd` is also useful.